# Xcode 9 vector images programmatically

Tags: xcode, vector, asset-catalog

Xcode 9 now lets us store PDF vectors in an Asset Catalog, and check the Preserve Vector Data flag to retain the vector information after the compile.

I know you can just set an image with `UIImage imageNamed` to make use of the vector.

What I'd like to know is how to get at the vector programmatically. For example, if I want a copy of that vector that's 900 points high, how can I get one out of the Asset Catalog.

Ideally it would be something like:

```
UIImage imageNamed:withHeight:
```

…but this does not exist.

Is what I want to do impossible right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `UIImage` to an `UIImageView`, then set the `contentMode` to `.scaleToFill` and finally setting the size of the UIImageView.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "circle")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I guess that would work. I would probably load the UIImage separately so that I could get the aspect ratio of the image, then I could size the UIImageView accordingly.